# Maven plugin to inject svn info in prepare-package phase

Tags: maven, svn

I am already using `maven-dependency-plugin` to inject some externally built dependencies in the WAR artifact during the `prepare-package` phase. It works well because I don't want those dependencies to be part of the code base the WAR is made out of.

The next thing I would like is to do something like a file dump of `svn info` (which lists basic versioning info, such as the versioning branch, latest revision etc) and have that file included in my `webapps` dir so that it can be visible in the deployed application. Of course, I can write a script in half a dozen languages to do this but I would like to do it completely inside Maven. I have been successful thus far in my CI efforts to contain all the tasks in the universe of maven plugins, which is nice.

I am aware of [maven-scm-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/plugin-info.html) but I am not sure it does what I need.